# Use PuTTY & winSCP to SSH using .local domain

Tags: putty

I'm trying to move over to host and domain names with my local networked Pis, but I need to start by being able to use PuTTY & WinSCP. It works well using IP's. I've already set up the host and domain names (using Avahi).

How do I use PuTTY and/or WinSCP with the domain name instead? (`raspberrypi.local` / `raspberrypi.home`)

Comment: Have you installed Apple Bonjour?

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but how does Apple Bonjour fit into the picture?

Comment: It's a daemon for supporting the Zeroconf protocol (which is used by Avahi) on Windows

Answer (score 3):

I connect to my Pi with `ssh pi@hostname.local`. This should work with similar GUI ssh programs.

You can connect from Linux e.g. other Pi and OS X. This is sometimes problematic with some versions of Windows and networks which use `.local` in a non-standard way. (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.local) Give this a try BEFORE you start fiddling with Windows or router networking files.

You need to make sure each Pi has a unique hostname.

Comment: I will look into all these thanks. I prefer not to have to fiddle with any default settings to keep things simple. Having so many crashes on my local network, all I want is the simplest way to have a non-conflicted local network and still be able to SSH and SCP between the PCs.

Answer (score 1):

Look for *DHCP server* in your router's configuration and there you should have some text field labeled *Local domain* (or similar).
If you have `lan` there then you have to use `raspberrypi.lan` on your computer. If you change it to eg. `local` then you will have to use `raspberrypi.local`.

Sometimes you can't change it and some times router forces you to use just `raspberrypi`, without any `.local` or `.lan`.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your host file(Linux : /etc/hosts Windows: C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc)  and add a line that points to your Raspberry ..

For Example:

```
10.0.0.1 raspberrypi.local
10.0.0.1 raspberrypi.home
```

10.0.0.1 should be changed with your raspberry pi ip address

You need administrator rights to change the file