# can you ssh from 1 raspberry pi to another raspberry pi?

Tags: ssh

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way via ssh or any other means to connect one raspberry pi to another.
Let me know if you know,

Answer (score 2):

You can easily `ssh` into the Pi (or any other 'NIX) box, provided it has `ssh` enabled and a network connection so they can reach each other.

See the following for a convenient way to do this on a local network without knowing IP. This should work on recent Raspbian.

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37652/8697

You can also install a GUI e.g. `FileZilla`.